# 2d to Pseudo 3d graphics

Tags: android, graphics, 3d, 2d

I've made a simple program that draws a series of parallel lines to make a rectangle on the canvas.  What I'd like to do is take that rectangle and transform it to look like its 3d, from a first person style view.  I can accomplish this with the graphics.camera class rotateX, but I would prefer to do it manually.

I've seen a lot of examples of taking a known 3d point and converting it to a 2d point on the screen, but I'm not sure how to apply that to what I'm doing.  Since the lines are being drawn in 2d, there is no 3d point for me to transform.

So if the line is being drawn in 2d with:

```
canvas.drawLine(Xstart, Ystart, Xend, Yend, paint);
```

How do I find the new Xend and Yend to make it look 3d?

Comment: How *much* "3d" do you want? 45 degrees?